# Loading/Buffering text while loading audio in html5 custom player with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-audio, audio-player

I found a custom html5 audio player and successfully redesigned it, now I want to add a "loading/buffering" text while player is loading audio (otherwise users may freak out because nothing happening after they hit play).

Here is the code to explain:

```js
function calculateTotalValue(length) {
  var minutes = Math.floor(length / 60),
    seconds_int = length - minutes * 60,
    seconds_str = seconds_int.toString(),
    seconds = seconds_str.substr(0, 2),
    time = minutes + ':' + seconds

  return time;
}

function calculateCurrentValue(currentTime) {
  var current_hour = parseInt(currentTime / 3600) % 24,
    current_minute = parseInt(currentTime / 60) % 60,
    current_seconds_long = currentTime % 60,
    current_seconds = current_seconds_long.toFixed(),
    current_time = (current_minute < 10 ? "0" + current_minute : current_minute) + ":" + (current_seconds < 10 ? "0" + current_seconds : current_seconds);

  return current_time;
}

function initProgressBar() {
  var player = document.getElementById('player');
  var length = player.duration
  var current_time = player.currentTime;

  // calculate total length of value
  var totalLength = calculateTotalValue(length)
  jQuery(".end-time").html(totalLength);

  // calculate current value time
  var currentTime = calculateCurrentValue(current_time);
  jQuery(".start-time").html(currentTime);

  var progressbar = document.getElementById('seekObj');
  progressbar.value = (player.currentTime / player.duration);
  progressbar.addEventListener("click", seek);

  if (player.currentTime == player.duration) {
    $('#play-btn').removeClass('pause');
  }

  function seek(evt) {
    var percent = evt.offsetX / this.offsetWidth;
    player.currentTime = percent * player.duration;
    progressbar.value = percent / 100;
  }
};

function initPlayers(num) {
  // pass num in if there are multiple audio players e.g 'player' + i

  for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    (function() {

      // Variables
      // ----------------------------------------------------------
      // audio embed object
      var playerContainer = document.getElementById('player-container'),
        player = document.getElementById('player'),
        isPlaying = false,
        playBtn = document.getElementById('play-btn');

      // Controls Listeners
      // ----------------------------------------------------------
      if (playBtn != null) {
        playBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
          togglePlay()
        });
      }

      // Controls & Sounds Methods
      // ----------------------------------------------------------
      function togglePlay() {
        if (player.paused === false) {
          player.pause();
          isPlaying = false;
          $('#play-btn').removeClass('pause');

        } else {
          player.play();
          $('#play-btn').addClass('pause');
          isPlaying = true;
        }
      }
    }());
  }
}

initPlayers(jQuery('#player-container').length);
```

Player code (source) on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/luke__duncan/pen/dpZVOr)

1. I want some text will be shown in the same "span" that shows
   "start time" (please see CodePen) while media is loading;
2. The text " 'loading.' 'loading..' 'loading...' " must changing on
   loop while media is loading;
3. When it is loaded the "loading" text must be changing on "start
   time" as it is now.

So basically I wat to put some text in start time  while it is not shows anything but zeroes

I'm new to JS

Thats why I need some help or point to right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the "readyState" event of the audio player to show hide loading.
There is already a "SetInterval" even which is getting fired so in that we can add this code to show/hide the "Loading"

1st add the loading element(You can put it where ever you want"

```
<h3 id="loading" style="display:none;">Loading</h3>
```

Now let's add the code to check "readystate" inside "SetInterval"

```
if(player.readyState>0&&player.readyState<4){
    $("#loading").show();
  }
  else{
    $("#loading").hide();
  }
```

You can read more about "readystate" [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_readystate.asp)

/As per the request I have changed the code to use the start time as loading, to make it work we don't have to add anything inside html but need to do some changes in JS

First, add this inside "togglePlay" functions pay condition in the "else" block.

```
$(".start-time").html("Loading...");
```

After this inside "initProgressBar()" function replace the "jQuery(".start-time").html(currentTime);" with the below code

```
 if (player.readyState === 4) {
    jQuery(".start-time").html(currentTime);
  }
```

so how it will work, When you click play button the start time text will show as "Loading" but once the file is loaded and the player is ready to play the text will be changed to "start time", Hope it works. Also updated the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/shubhamkumarnayak/pen/MBLGOd) for better understanding

You can find the full code in the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/shubhamkumarnayak/pen/MBLGOd?editors=1111)

Comment: You’re on fire! @Shubham, this is exactly what I wanted! Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Is it possible to put it in the start time span, and only timer will show only after loading text disappears? @Shubham

Comment: Maybe I should be more specific in my previous comment, I was talking about Both timers shows up only after loading complete and loading text disappears @Shubham

Comment: @AndrewK not an issue, the endtime html need to be added inside the condition as well, I will do the changes

Comment: Thank you!, again @Shubham, I think we can consider this question as an answered.)

Comment: @AndrewK I think all of your questions are answered :)

Comment: I've changed the end time span to show rem time first (as permanent, without toggle classes), it works great in general except rem time pops up a little bit later the n the start time timer, there is any way I can fix that? @Shubham

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177943/discussion-between-shubham-and-andrew-k).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) to cycle through the different 'loading' text and [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval)  when the player's play [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play#Example) is done.

Here's a basic example:

```
var dots = 1;
var loading = setInterval(function(){ 
  dots = (dots % 3) + 1;
  $(".start-time").text("Loading" + Array(dots + 1).join("."));
  console.log($(".start-time").text());
}, 250);

player.play().then(function() {
  clearInterval(loading); 
}).catch((error) => {
  $(".start-time").text("Error loading");
});
```

Comment: I think I get the point but my main chalange at the beginning is how to make it work in the same code: State one: nothing is shown at start time "span"; Step two: user hit play - loading text showing at start time "span" while media is loading; State three: media is loaded and playing - time value is showing in start time "span". I need it to be a "light" adjustment to existing JS, because before user hit play the start time "span" is taken for another task. @DéricDallaire

Comment: Yes, just use my code within the else block of your togglePlay method and you will have the expected result. It's possible you don't see the loading when you click play if the promise is resolved too fast. Try loading a bigger file. See [codepen](https://codepen.io/bubblesphere/pen/xJmqLR)

Comment: This is exactly what I told you about, “loading” is changing to 00:00 (zeroed) time value and then nothing is happening for a while, users might think that player is stack, so I want to “loading text” will be shown till the start timer start it’s countdown (till user hear that player actually plays music).@DéricDallaire

Comment: Yes, while the file is loading, the "loading" text appears. Considering the file loads quickly, the loading doesn't always  have the time to show because it starts instantly. I modified the codepen to simulate a file taking 5 seconds to load. It's important that you get a better grasp of how Promises work in javascript. In the context of the player, the promise "is fulfilled when playback has been started, or is rejected if for any reason playback cannot be started." [src](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play#Return_value)

Comment: I had opened your codpen again on a mobile, and this time it stuck on loading loop, and play button changing delay. Did you change something after my previous comment? (tested the original code - it works well on my mobile now) @DéricDallaire

Comment: Oh, I see, you changing “time to load”, and you mentioned it in your comment. I will check on it later on a laptop. Thank You

Comment: Can you please take back the codepen to previous state without simulation, I want to make sure that I didn't mess up anything. And if I say I wanted to make "loading text" static in the future (for example just 'loading') what do I have to modify to achieve that? @Déric Dallaire